# my objects glitch through plane when i try to make them particals

Tags: particles

how do i fix this so the pear objects are actually on the plane instead of inside

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its fixed i just had to go to edit mode on my pear and select all of it and move it away from the center which is the little orange dot